# Spring Boot java with Mongodb

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-boot

```
package com.javatechie.spring.mongo.api.resource;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;

import org.bson.Document;
import org.bson.json.JsonReader;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.QualifierAnnotationAutowireCandidateResolver;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.DeleteMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.javatechie.spring.mongo.api.model.Book;
import com.javatechie.spring.mongo.api.repository.BookRepository;

@RestController
public class BookController {

    @Autowired
    private BookRepository repository;

    @Autowired
    private  MongoTemplate mongoTemplate;

    @PostMapping("/addBook")
    public String saveBook(@RequestBody Book book) {
        repository.save(book);
        return "Added book with id : " + book.getId();
    }

   @GetMapping("/findAllBooks")
   public List<Book> getBooks() {
       String jsonCommand = "{ aggregate: 'Book', pipeline: [ { $project: { _id: 0, 'bookName': 1 
    } } ], cursor: { } }";
       Document resultDoc = mongoTemplate.executeCommand(jsonCommand);
       System.out.println(resultDoc);
       return repository.findAll();
   }
```

I am successfully able to print a specific field on the console using this
String jsonCommand = "{ aggregate: 'Book', pipeline: [ { $project: { _id: 0, 'bookName': 1 } } ], cursor: { } }";
but I want to print specific data for example in my bookName field there are many books so I want to print only those which are Python currently it is printing all bookName.

Kindly help me out here iam stuck

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to add [$match](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/) to your aggregation pipeline. Like `{$match:{ "bookName":"Python"}}`

Your aggregation query is looking for all documents in collection by default. And then returns you the fields described by rules in projection. In your case rule `{ _id: 0, 'bookName': 1 }` means to show
`bookName` and hide `_id` fields of document.

Adding `$match` stage before `$project` will filter document before they will be projected.

Comment: Perhaps you should also explain why this will help to solve the OP problem.